# Using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel numbers have decimals

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel to import a csv. The csv file looks like:

```
id;parent;name
1;0;Home
2;0;Contact
3;2;Thank you
4;0;Blog
5;4;Article 1
6;4;Article 2
```

The code is:

```
$rows = Excel::load('file.csv')->get();
$rows->each(function($row) {
    dd($row->toArray());
});
```

The output is like:

```
array:3 [
  "id" => 1.0
  "parent" => 0.0
  "name" => "Home"
]
```

So the regular numbers have a decimal added to it. How do I make it a regular integer without decimals? I know how to do it afterwards, but is it possible at `load` also?